# Confused by the SVD of a real symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, symmetric-matrices

For a real symmetric matrix *A*, it's true that:

$$A A^T = A^T A = A^2$$

And since the right and left singular vectors of $A$ are the eigenvectors of $A^T A$ and $A A^T$ respectively, the right and left singular vectors ought to be identical.

Here's the particular situation that is causing my confusion. Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 & -2 & 2 \\ 1 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 & 3 & -2 \\ 2 & 1 & -2 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Now when I try to take the SVD of this matrix, the matrices $U$ and $V$, of the left and right singular vectors respectively, are identical. Just as I thought they would be. In particular, for $U$, $\Sigma$, and $V$ I get:

$$U = V = \begin{bmatrix} -0.718 & 0.202 & 0.177 & -0.642 \\ -0.221 & 0.789 & 0.178 & 0.544 \\ 0.557 & 0.580 & -0.288 & -0.520 \\ -0.353 & 0.010 & -0.924 & 0.144 \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix} 6.845 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2.269 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 2.198 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1.084 \end{bmatrix}$$

But if I use this to calculate $U \Sigma V^T$ I don't get $A$. This already confuses me, but to make matters worse, if I take $V$ to be $U$ except with the signs changed on the third column, then it comes out correctly! I feel like I must be misunderstanding something about the SVD or Eigenvectors in general, as I thought that as long as each eigenvector had norm 1, it didn't matter what the sign of it was (i.e. I think about it as more of an eigendirection). **Can anyone point out why I'm getting these results?**

Comment: Have you tried $U^T\Sigma U$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE that while U == V,  the matricies U and V are not symmetric. The definition of the SVD: A = USV' (where the prime indicates the Hermitian (conjugate transpose) of the matrix) - so this is probably your mistake - you probably forgot to apply the transpose - or your math language may have already supplied it for you.

In a lot of the languages with built-in SVD (ie Matlab, Python...) you need to be careful that the SVD function might return U,S,V' (the Hermitian of V)

for example in python you would have
U,S,VH = svd(A)

This produces the same U,S,V as you have above - except that it gives the Hermitian of V

Putting it all back together... (in python 'dot' is used for matrix multiplication)

B = dot(U,dot(diag(S),VH))

yielding abs(B-A).max() = 9.992e-16, somewhere around machine epsilon

Comment: For a real matrix, such as the V in my example, the Hermitian is the same as the transpose, right? In which case V' = V^T = U^T, but calculating U Sigma U^T still does not result in the right answer.

Comment: Yep B = U\*S\*V' should do it (in Matlab http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html) - are you using matlab? if so enter: U\*Sigma\*V'

Comment: I'm definitely not forgetting to apply the transpose, per your answer. I AM applying the transpose, but still getting the wrong result. Using the U,S,V from my example, U S V^T = U S U^T   !=   A. I'd also like to add that if I use an external SVD calculation, such as [this](http://comnuan.com/cmnn01004/) one, U and V are not identical (why?) but rather V is identical to U except for the third column.

Comment: are you using the full precision of the numbers in the matrices - and the ones shown up above are just rounded off? I will have a look at the external one (when I use the full precision numbers in python - I get a fair representation of your matrix)

Comment: I see that in the external calculator - the U and V are different - in python I am also noticing that they are not equal - it then occurs to me that U=V only in the case of a positive definite symmetric matrix (all the eigenvalues are positive) - this is not the case for your matrix [6.84462111, -2.19751698,  1.08436446,  2.26853141]
] - you need a separate U and V - if we do this same trick on the matrix: P = AA^T - then U = V

Comment: I honestly don't know if I'm just going crazy or what, but I went ahead and did the SVD using both wolfram and the website I linked earlier, and took a screenshot of the results. In both cases, U and V are not identical (note the third columns). [Wolfram Results](http://imgur.com/M1gxVVs), and [Other Results](http://imgur.com/XHY9vFE) ||| Oops I just saw your latest comment. My next question then, Is why are U and V different given that they are the eigenvalues of AA' and A'A, which are identical? Is this a computer issue or something in the mathematics?

Comment: The matrix must be positive definite and symmetric for U to be equal to V - and in your case it is not positive definite

Comment: I want to mark this as answered but I'm still a little puzzled. We've identified that U = V only for a positive definite symmetric matrix, but that seems to be at odds with the fact that U and V are the eigenvectors of A'A and AA', which are the same? Are U and V **not** the eigenvectors of those matrices? Can you see where my confusion is coming from?

Comment: Indeed -I see your point by the definition of the SVD - in my calculations abs(U) = abs(V)- and they are the same except in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th column, in those cases they are just -1 times those columns - and any constant times an eigenvector is still an eigenvector - so technically they are still orthoganol eigenvectors of A^TA and AA^T

Comment: You are correct, they are still the eigenvectors of their respective matrices, but now I've come to find out that not all sets of orthonormal eigenvectors are valid for the SVD? This is unfortunate because my entire algorithm for finding the SVD hinges on finding eigenvectors of AA' and A'A (using a QR algorithm if that's important). If I can't always use the eigenvector set that my algorithm spits out, how can I know when and which columns I need to change the signs on? I'll mark this answer as accepted, even though I still have so many unanswered questions about this phenomenon. Thanks!

Comment: Are you following the approach in Golub and Kahan (https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/GlbKhnSv.pdf) ? I believe they also used QR factorization - it might also be outlined in Golub and Van Loan

Comment: What I don't understand is your postulate on the 4th line "the right and left singular vectors ought to be identical". The SVD algorithm has no reason to yield identical vectors...

Comment: You can try the alternating A = Q1R1, R1 = L1P1', and then look for another decomposition L1= Q2R2 ... at each step the Qk and Pk' are unitary and eventually your upper or lower triangular parts are simply diagonal - then Q1Q2...QN are U and PN'..P1' is V'

Answer (score 5):

If $A$ is symmetric then $A^TA = A^2$ and the eigenvalues of $A^2$ are the squares of the eigenvalues of $A$, and therefore the singular values are $\sigma=|\lambda|$.  The eigenvectors of $A^TA=A^2$ are just the same as those of $A$; call these $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$ and let $V=[v_1\,v_2\,\cdots\,v_n]$.  Assume for simplicity that $A$ is non-singular.  Then $u = \frac{1}{\sigma} Av$ for each $v$ and corresponding singular value and therefore $u=\frac{\lambda}{|\lambda|} v = sign(\lambda) v$.  Let Q be the diagonal matrix containing the numbers $sign(\lambda)$ for each $\lambda$.  Then $U=VQ$, and the singular value decomposition is $A=U\Sigma V^T = V (Q \Sigma) V^T$.  So, the part $Q\Sigma$ takes care of getting the correct sign for the eigenvalues and it is what you were missing, in other words, $Q\Sigma = diag(\lambda's)$

Answer (score 4):

This is a common mistake when trying to calculate the SVD of symmetric matrices for homework type problems, the root of the issue being the non-uniqueness of eigenvectors.

We know from the SVD of $A=U\Sigma V^T$, that $A^TA = V\Sigma^2 V^T$ (remember that $A$ is symmetric), so find the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of $B=A^TA$. This gives you $V$ and $\Sigma$ (by taking a square root of the eigenvalues), respectively.

Here is the trap. If you were to try to find $U$ by computing the eigenvectors of $AA^T$, you would end up back with $B$ and might conclude that $U=V$. That is wrong, since eigenvectors are not unique. Instead, use the SVD equation, and right multiply by $V$ to get: $AV=U\Sigma=[u_1\sigma_1 \, \ldots \, u_n\sigma_n]$. You already know $A,V$ and $\Sigma$, so normalize the $i^{th}$ column of the product $AV$ by $\sigma_i$ to get $u_i$, the $i^{th}$ column of $U$. This way you get the correct SVD of $A$.

PS: If one or more of the singular values are zero, then the above approach fails. In such cases, you will need to start with those $u_i$'s which correspond to non-zero singular values, and apply a Gram Schmidt procedure with the canonical basis to find the remaining orthonormal vectors to get $U$.